# Determining whether jQuery has not found any element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm using jQuery's selectors, especially id selector:

```
$("#elementId")...
```

How should I determine whether jQuery has found the element or not? 
Even If the element with the specified id doesn't exist the next statement give me: `[object Object]`

```
alert($("#idThatDoesnotexist"));
```

Answer (score 206, accepted):

`$('#idThatDoesnotexist').length` is what you're looking for. (If it finds nothing, this will `=== 0`.) So your conditional statement should probably be:

```
if($('#id').length) { /* code if found */ } else { /* code if not found */ }
```

You're getting an object returned from that alert because jQuery (almost) always returns the "jQuery object" when you use it, which is a wrapper for the elements jQuery's found that permits method chaining.

Comment: You don't need the zero, $('#id').length is enough (zero == false in javascript)

Comment: @David the fact that you don't _Need_ it doesn't necessarily makes it redundant, at first glance IMO it makes it more clear.

Comment: @Abir: It only makes it more clear until you're used to the syntax without it, testing for truthiness rather than explicitly 0.  I suggest simply getting used to the syntax without the `== 0`, you'll see it everywhere.

Comment: @ScottStafford, for more clearance, you can also use `if (!!$('#id').length)`, that do a boolean cast.

Comment: You should also consider if the benefits of saving a couple of characters offset the potential confusion when someone unfamiliar with the nuances of Javascript reads the code. Not best practice as far as maintainability is concerned in my opinion.

Answer (score 27):

Futuraprime is right but you can shorten your syntax by doing the following:

```
if ($("#id").length) {
   //at least one element was found
} else {
   //no elements found
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
!$.isEmptyObject($.find('#id'))
```

This will return true if the element exists and false if it doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#my_selector').length > 0 
$('#my_selector').get(0) !== undefined
$('#my_selector')[0] !== undefined
```

This is the basic, now do whatever you want.