# what's the meaning of this jquery if?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

this is a jquery 'if', i don't know what the if part do?  because it doesn't compare anything!  is it check if div element exist?

```
if($('div[id="product_1"]')){
    $('div[id="product_1"]').slideDown();
}
```

Comment: It looks like this code can easily be compressed by 80%. And after that the 3 remaining lines can be stripped to just one.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a buggy code. Using jQuery, `$(something)` always evaluates as truish in a `if` statement (it's an object and it's not `null`).

If you want to test if there is at least one matching element, use

```
if ($(something).length) {
```

Note that when using jQuery functions, you don't have to test if there is a match. There won't be any error if your reduce your whole code to

```
$('div[id="product_1"]').slideDown();
```

even if `$('div[id="product_1"]').length` is `0`. The clean way is **not** to test.

Comment: Is that true? I'm not a jQuery expert, but I think the first if statement is searching for a div in the DOM with an ID of "product_1". If the DOM element doesn't exist, then I think `null` is returned, and the if statement fails. Am I wrong? In vanilla JS, at least, if no elements with a particular ID exist, getElementById returns `null`. Sorry if jQuery is different and I'm wrong.

Comment: @HartleySan Yes, you're wrong : `$(something)` is an object, not `null`.

Comment: All right. Thanks for confirming that. I didn't want to cause any additional confusion.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I just confirmed on the following SO thread that the jQuery object is always returned, so yeah, you have to test the length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877654/determining-whether-jquery-has-not-found-any-element

Comment: @HartleySan: `$(selector)` return an array of elements that match the selector. If nothing matches an empty array is returned.