# Karma: cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to do unit tests on my Angularjs code using karma.
This is my conf file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: './',

// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
  'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js',
  'https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-mocks.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js',
  'js/app.js',
  'js/controllers/AffairesCtrl.js'
],



// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
});
};
```

I'm testing a function which has the following code:

```
document.getElementById('case').style.display="none";
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

But, if I replace the javascript code with jQuery code:

```
$("#case").css("display","none");
```

Then, the test is a success and the previous error disappear.

Do you know why I get this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Had the same issue, this was for removing a loading spinner, but the spinner lived on the index.html, not on the component html. I just wrapped the code in an if, testing to see if it existed, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely because your document has no element with an id of "case".

See the documentation on [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

jQuery on the other hand does not return null if no elements exist [as mentioned in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877654/determining-whether-jquery-has-not-found-any-element). Therefore no error.