# Adding a class with toggleClass cannot be replaced

Tags: jquery

I have a filter button that toggles some children elements from the default disabled state (.class) to enabled (.class). I use toggleclass() to remove the `.disabled` and add the `.enabled` class which is empty in style.css.

Though I successfully remove the .disabled class and add the .enabled class, on the reverse transition my code fails. I cannot get back to the disabled state. Here's my code:

**Jquery**

```
$(".filter-btn").click(function(){
        var button = $(this);
        button.toggleClass("btn-default btn-primary");
        button.html("xxxxxxxxxxx: ");
        var container = button.closest(".form-group.sr-page");
        if(container.find(".disabled")){
            container.find(".disabled").toggleClass("disabled enabled");
        }
        else if (container.find(".enabled"))
            container.find(".enabled").toggleClass("disabled enabled");
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled {
    color: #AAAAAA;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.enabled {

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use *both* `enabled` and `disabled` classes? Can't you just use `enabled` and detect non-`enabled`-ness by the absence of the class name?

Comment: I have classes that are not disabled, like the filter button, so imposing "disabled-ness" to all elements would be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have an additional closing `}` (or a missing opening `{` after the `else if`). Perhaps a typo.

Second, instead of this (which just changes the enabled state of disabled/enabled elements):

```
if (container.find(".disabled")) {
    container.find(".disabled").toggleClass("disabled enabled");
} else if (container.find(".enabled"))
    container.find(".enabled").toggleClass("disabled enabled");
```

you can use this:

```
container.find(".enabled, .disabled").toggleClass("enabled disabled");
```

Which not only works - https://jsfiddle.net/63m1oh6p/ - but is far simpler than the original code.
It's slightly different, though - it will toggle *all* elements that are *either* enabled *or* disabled, while the original code will toggle only one group.

Now, as you're probably wondering **why your code doesn't work**, we need to focus on this line:

```
if (container.find(".disabled")) {
```

Next, let's look at the documentation of `find()` -

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these
>   elements in the DOM tree **and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements**.

Moreover, if you look right over the *Description* paragraph, you'll note that the return value of the functions is the [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), where we can read the following:

> A jQuery object **may be empty, containing no DOM elements**. You can create an empty jQuery object with $() (that is, passing no arguments at all). A jQuery object may also be empty if a selector doesn't select any elements, or if a **chained method filters out all the elements**. It is not an error; any further methods called on that jQuery object simply have no effect since they have no elements to act upon.

And you had this:

```
if (container.find(".disabled")) {
```

I guess you should already be understanding what happened.
`if` will **not** pass only if the given value is faulty, that is `0`, `null`, an empty string.
And `find` returned a fully valid true-ty object. So your check *always* passed, whether there were selected elements or not.

Now your question perhaps changed to *how* to check if a jQuery selector returned any DOM elements. Read about it here: [Determining whether jQuery has not found any element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2877654).

Comment: Great answer AI.G.! I had guessed that the problem had to do with the empty object and the faulty-ness of the if-statement, but I prefered the SO's wise men advice to reading the docs ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be better off by creating a separate class to denote which dom elements to be enabled or disabled. Look at the example below:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="button" value="Click me" class="filter-btn btn-default" />
  <input type="text" value="Change this one" class="enabled enabled-disabled" />
  <input type="text" value="Do not change" />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".filter-btn").click(function(){
    var button = $(this);
    button.toggleClass("btn-default btn-primary");
    var container = button.closest(".form-group");
    if(container.find(".enabled-disabled")){
      container.find(".enabled-disabled").toggleClass("disabled enabled");
    }
});
```

[Here is demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tejsoft/mw7yq64v/1/)

Comment: This is the solution I finally chose, but I would like to know why the above piece of code is not working

Comment: @AI.G has given a detailed explanation below. Your first call to find elements with "disabled" [container.find(".disabled")] class has made the jQuery object (here: container) empty. In the next call to find DOM elements with "enabled" class is making the search on an empty jQuery object.