# How does jQuery $(this) on Clicked element or class work?

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement, click, element

I have a simple html snippet.

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="A1_B1 symptom">
        <ul><li><a href="#" class="hit">Click Symptom</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="A2_B2 remedy">
        <ul><li><a href="#" class="hit">Click Remedy</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now for the click action...

```
$(document).on("click", ".hit", function (ev) {
if($(this).parents(".symptom"))
    alert("Symptom Clicked");
if($(this).parents(".remedy"))
    alert("Remedy Clicked");
});
```

$(this) is supposed to refer only the element that I have clicked. Why does it alert both the alert statements even if the if conditions do not satisfy?

Comment: `parents` returns an object and objects are truthy values in JavaScript.  Use `parents(...).length` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as following

```
$(document).on("click", ".hit", function (ev) {
if($(this).parents(".symptom").length>0)
    alert("Symptom Clicked");
if($(this).parents(".remedy").length>0)
    alert("Remedy Clicked");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1mz8s73b/

Comment: Strange! What does length indicate here?

Comment: @Jay, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877654/determining-whether-jquery-has-not-found-any-element/2877672