# what is the behavior of jquery when filter on an empty jquery (`.contents()`) / when all is filtered out

Tags: jquery, is-empty

what is the behavior of jquery when filter on an empty jquery (`.contents()`) / when all is filtered out

*(some result observed during learning & testing, not really a question. 

post for others that may wonder 

see my answer below)*

Answer (score 0):

basically, it returns an empty jquery -- **a jquery object with length 0**

#### code ex

```js
  // <div id="testCC"></div>
  // <div id="testBB">fourNg normal-3 twoNg normal-1 zero one two <span>overlap3-ori_do_nothing four</span> four <span>merge5</span> <span>merge6</span> seven eight 1st_mono_2nd_bi_replace_merge_9 1st_mono_2nd_bi_replace_merge_10 eleven twelve</div>

  $(function () {
    let jqElt_result;

    // #>>> get $
    // get an non existing html element -- return empty jquery
    jqElt_result = $('#nonexist');
    // console.log(jqElt_result);
    console.log(jqElt_result.length);

    // #>>> content
    // normal get content
    jqElt_result = $('#testBB').contents();
    // console.log(jqElt_result);
    console.log(jqElt_result.length);

    // get content on an empty html element -- return empty jquery
    jqElt_result = $('#testCC').contents();
    // console.log(jqElt_result);
    console.log(jqElt_result.length);

    // get content on an non existing html element -- return empty jquery
    jqElt_result = $('#nonexist').contents();
    // console.log(jqElt_result);
    console.log(jqElt_result.length);

    // #>>> filter
    // normal filter
    jqElt_result = $('#testBB').contents().filter((i, n) => n.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE);
    // console.log(jqElt_result);
    console.log(jqElt_result.length);

    // filter everything to false -- return empty jquery
    jqElt_result = $('#testBB').contents().filter(() => false);
    // console.log(jqElt_result);
    console.log(jqElt_result.length);

    // filter on empty content of an empty html element -- return empty jquery
    jqElt_result = $('#testCC').contents().filter(() => false);
    // console.log(jqElt_result);
    console.log(jqElt_result.length);
  });

  // [Output]
  //
  // jQuery.fn.init
  // 0
  // jQuery.fn.init(7) [#text, span, #text, span, #text, span, #text, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
  // 7
  // jQuery.fn.init(0) [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
  // 0
  // jQuery.fn.init(0) [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init]
  // 0
  // jQuery.fn.init(4) [#text, #text, #text, #text, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(7)]
  // 4
  // jQuery.fn.init(0) [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(7)]
  // 0
  // jQuery.fn.init(0) [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(0)]
  // 0
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testCC"></div>
<div id="testBB">fourNg normal-3 twoNg normal-1 zero one two <span>overlap3-ori_do_nothing four</span> four <span>merge5</span> <span>merge6</span> seven eight 1st_mono_2nd_bi_replace_merge_9 1st_mono_2nd_bi_replace_merge_10 eleven twelve</div>
```

#### empty jquery object -- a jquery object with length 0

> []
>
> `$('#idThatDoesnotexist').length` is what you're looking for. (If it finds nothing, this will `=== 0`.) So your conditional statement should probably be:
>
> <>
>
> [Determining whether jQuery has not found any element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877654/determining-whether-jquery-has-not-found-any-element)
>
> []
>
> `if ( $( "#myDiv" ).length ) {`
>
> <>
>
> https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/